# prevent change event in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery ui accordion , in that i have a text box as a accordion header , now when i am trying
to type a space in text box accordion change and changestart event fire so how would i prevent this thing while typing space in a input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

- [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

within a `keydown` or `keypress` or `keyup` event handler. You can check the `keyCode` or even better the value of `which` from the event object there and execute both functions from above.

Alternativly, you can just `return false;` which actually will trigger the same functions for you.

Example:

```
$('input:text').bind('keypress', function(event){
   if(event.which === 32)
      return(false);
});
```

Comment: this wont allow me to type space in a textbox

Comment: Done !! using following code thanks 
    
    if (event.which == 32) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    }

Comment: @hunt: yes indeed you're right. My bad. You just need to prevent the `event bubbling` in that case.